# How to pre-process BigQuery data coming from Stackdriver

Tags: google-bigquery, stackdriver

I am currently exporting logs from **Stackdriver** to **BigQuery** using sinks. But i am only interessted in the **jsonPayload**. I would like to ignore pretty much everything else. 
But since the table creation and data insertion happens automatically, i could not do this. 
Is there a way to preprocess data coming from **sink** to store only what matters? 
If the answer is no, is there a way to run a cron job each day to copy yesterday data into a seperate table and then remove it? (knowing that the tables are named using **timestamps** which makes it possible to query them by day)

Comment: No, you can't control the schema with Stackdriver sinks to BigQuery. One strategy, is to use views on top of the raw data to only surface the columns/data that you're interested in. Would this fit your requirements? Or, do you simply want to throw away the data you're not interested in to try and save of storage costs?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am already using views but I am hoping to get rid of the data that I don't need.is there a way for this?

Comment: Are you trying to simply save some money on storage?

Comment: That is what I am trying to do

Comment: Storage costs are negligible i.e. cheap. I'd argue that the time needed to think about this and build something is going to cost more than just storing it, not to mention the queries and DML to build a solution :) If you *really* want to get rid of them, then something like running a scheduled query each X hour/day which reads from raw data the columns you want and writes it to a new table. Then delete the contents from the raw table using a DML statement.

Comment: thank you. i will leave them now and consider the scheduled query later

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know both options mentioned are currently not possible in the GCP platform. On my end I've also tried to create an internal reproduction of your request and noticed that there isn't a way to solely filter the jsonPayload.

I would therefore suggest creating a feature request in regards to your ask on the following public issue tracker [link](http://issuetracker.google.com). Note that feature requests do not have an ETA as to when they'll processed or if they'll be implemented.

Comment: See my comments above on the OP's question :)

Comment: @GrahamPolley Would it be possible if you can add your above comment as an answer on this post? This is to help out the community in case such a question arises again in the future.